# GridSearchCV + StratifiedKfold in case of TFIDF

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, tf-idf, grid-search

I am working on a classification problem where I need to predict the class of textual data. I need to do hyper parameter tuning for my classification model for which I am thinking to use `GridSearchCV`. I need to do `StratifiedKFold` as well because my data is imbalanced. I am aware of the fact that `GridSearchCV` internally uses `StratifiedKFold` if we have multiclass classification.

**I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47778403/computing-tf-idf-on-the-whole-dataset-or-only-on-training-data) that in case of `TfidfVectorizer` we apply `fit_transform` to train data and only transform to test data.**

This is what I have done below using `StratifiedKFold`.

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=5)

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    iteration = iteration+1
    print(f"Iteration number {iteration}")
    X_train, y_train = X.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[train_index]
    X_test, y_test = X.iloc[test_index], y.iloc[test_index]

    train_tfid = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train.values.astype('U'))
    test_tfid = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(X_test.values.astype('U'))

    svc_model = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
    svc_model.fit(train_tfid, y_train.values.ravel())
```

The accuracy/f1 I am getting is not good so thought of doing hyper parameter tuning using GridSearchCV.
In GridSearchCV we do

```
c_space = np.logspace(-5, 8, 15) 
param_grid = {'C': c_space} 

# Instantiating logistic regression classifier 
logreg = LogisticRegression() 

# Instantiating the GridSearchCV object 
logreg_cv = GridSearchCV(logreg, param_grid, cv = 5) 

logreg_cv.fit(X, y)
```

According to me `logreg_cv.fit(X, y)` would internally split the X in `X_train`, `X_test` k times and then would do predictions to give us the best estimator.

In my case what should be X? If it's X which is generated after `fit_transform` then internally when X is split into train and test, the test data has undergone `fit_transform` but ideally it should undergo only transform.

My concern is that in my case, inside `GridSearchCV` how would I be able to control that `fit_transform` is applied only to train data and transform is applied to test data (validation data).

because if it internally applies fit_transform to entire data then it is not a good practise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an exact scenario where you should be using `Pipeline` in `GridSearchCV`. First, create a pipeline with the required steps such as data preprocessing, feature selection and model. Once you call `GridSearchCV` on this pipeline, it will do the data processing only on training folds and then fit with the model.

Read [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) to understand more about the model selection module in sklearn.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
import numpy as np

cats = ['alt.atheism', 'sci.space']
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',
                                      remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'),
                                      categories=cats)
X, y = newsgroups_train.data, newsgroups_train.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.1, stratify=y)


my_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression())
])


parameters = {'clf__C': np.logspace(-5, 8, 15)}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(my_pipeline, param_grid=parameters,
                           cv=10, n_jobs=-1, scoring='accuracy')
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(grid_search.best_params_)
# {'clf__C': 0.4393970560760795}

grid_search.score(X_test, y_test)
# 0.8981481481481481
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that GridSearchCV, in this case, will vectorize, try to fit Logistic Regression and it's hyperparameters and this for a StratifiedKFold split of 10, then it returns the model and hyperparrameters with the best scores for those 10 folds?